# @EnableTransactionManagment annotation is not working with spring JtaTransactionManager

Tags: java, spring, transactions

I'm actually using two transaction manager objects in my spring java configuration
as shown below

```
    @Bean("jtaTranx")
    public PlatformTransactionManager jtaTransactionMangaer(){ 
        return new JtaTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

with class level annotated with @configuration and @EnableTransactionManagment.
When ever I'm trying to do some transactions using the @Transactional I'm getting an exception can't perform transaction during the managed transaction, can any one let me know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please add the code that is failing.

Comment: Why would you need 2 transaction managers when you are using JTA? You should only have a single one in that case.

Comment: Also we'll need to see the error.

Comment: It was requirement so I happen to implement both the transaction managers.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue using Embedded JtaTransactionManager. I have taken atomikos reference implementation form [here](https://www.atomikos.com)

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException, NamingException {
        EntityManagerFactory factory = entityManagerFactory().getObject();
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

    @Bean(name = "jtaTransactionManager")   
    public PlatformTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager() throws Throwable {
      UserTransaction userTransaction = userTransaction() ;
      TransactionManager transactionManager = atomikosTransactionManager() ;
      return new JtaTransactionManager(userTransaction, transactionManager );
    }

    @Bean
    public UserTransaction userTransaction() throws Throwable {
        UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(10000);
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    @Bean(initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager() throws Throwable {
        UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(false);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }
```